# Is there a free tool to integrate .NET Reflector with Visual Studio, besides TestDriven.NET?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, reflector

I love the **Go to Reflector** menu option installed by [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/). However, TestDriven.NET is not free for commercial use and so I do not have it at work.

Is there another tool out there that does just that - allows to jump to [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) from the source code in Visual Studio and which is totally free?

I know it is possible to develop a Visual Studio add-in that does it, but, alas, I have no time for it, so has one already been developed?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from the author of TestDriven.NET is it is very difficult to intergrate .NET Reflector with Visual Studio. He use to provide a free .NET Reflector Add-in but (I don't remember his reason) decided to roll it up into newer versions of TestDriven.NET. <strike>I believe the source code (`ReflectorVsAddin.zip`) for the original add-in is still out there.</strike> (Found the old .NET 1.1 / Visual Studio 2003 source code, see the update below.) Someone probably has the original ZIP file.

To use with older versions of Visual Studio, I still have either all or some of the files included in `ReflectorVsAddin.zip`. I am sure some hardy soul could disassemble them and create an add-in based on the techniques. Yet, searching on "Reflector Hosting" resulted in numerous articles on how to integrate .NET Reflector with your own application. I believe it would be easier to start from scratch. I personally, find using .NET Reflector externally outside of Visual Studio easier to use.

#### Update

*[Building the Reflector Add-In](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/reflectoraddin.aspx)*
By Jamie Cansdale
Making Reflector into a Visual Studio.NET Add-In

#### Update

See *[How to: Load Assemblies into the Reflection-Only Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331.aspx)*.

Comment: I would like to have the source code. Where can I found it and whether Jamie Cansdale (the author of the original plugin and TD.NET) allows to reuse it?

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded it. Hope I get some free time to examine it, though I doubt. Thanks anyway.

Comment: All I have are the originl binaries that I kept around for earlier versions of Visual Studio. ftp://missico.net/Reflector.VisualStudio.zip

Comment: Unfortunately, the codeproject article is irrelevant for VS2005 or VS2008.

Comment: True, but it is a start and helps flush out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Reflector have the Visual Studio add-in that you mention bundled with it for free.

Answer (score 0):

One parial solution might be for you to do the following:

1. Make sure you have Reflector registered so it shows on your context menu in windows explorer.
2. In visual studio, make sure the "Show all Files" button is clicked in your solution explorer
3. Go to the bin/Debug directory folder and right click on the directory
4. Choose "Open Folder in Windows Explorer"
5. Once windows explorer comes up, right click on your assembly and choose "Browse with Reflector"

This won't get you to the exact code you were looking at (like the TD.Net addin) but it will get you into reflector in a couple of clicks, just leaving you to use find to locate the code.

Comment: I have already an external VS tool that opens reflector on the target path of the currently open item. I still wonder if that is the best we can hope to achieve without TD.NET.

Comment: One can define external tools in VS - go to Tools|External Tools...
Specify the path to Reflector.exe and in the command line arguments one can give the path of the target exe/dll. Name the tool "Open Reflector". Running it will open the current exe/dll in Reflector. Using reflector url format you can even navigate to the source code of the currently open file. But, TD.NET allows to navigate to the source code of the current frame in the call stack, something which cannot be done via external tools facility.